# Check that value is object literal?

Tags: javascript

I have a value and want to know if it's an iteratable object literal, before I iterate it.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please define "iterable".

Answer (score 45):

This should do it for you:

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( someObject ) === '[object Object]' ) {
    // do your iteration
}
```

From **ECMAScript 5 Section 8.6.2** if you're interested:

> The value of the [[Class]] internal property is defined by this specification for every kind of built-in object. The value of the [[Class]] internal property of a host object may be any String value except one of "Arguments", "Array", "Boolean", "Date", "Error", "Function", "JSON", "Math", "Number", "Object", "RegExp", and "String". The value of a [[Class]] internal property is used internally to distinguish different kinds of objects. Note that this specification does not provide any means for a program to access that value except through Object.prototype.toString (see 15.2.4.2).

Comment: This is no longer guaranteed to work in ES6, as an object can change the value of its Symbol.toStringTag property, which is used to generate Object.prototype.toString's return value. See the note at: http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring It looks like the way to check if something's iterable now is to see if it's Symbol.iterator property is defined

Comment: `Object.prototype.toString` could be overridden; thus, not safe.

Comment: If its ever overwritten; that dev should be shot! Any prototypical structure can have its methods overwritten, and in turn would be useless if you could not depend on them.

Comment: for the ppl who still using to this answer be careful : `var str;  toString.call( str)` if the value is undefined or null it will comeback "object" in **IE < 9** and some mobiles . checkout first for undefined and null before you apply this condition .

Answer (score 9):

You could also do something like:

```
    if (someObject.constructor == Object) {
        // do your thing
    }
```

you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

Comment: If someObject is null, it doesn't have a constructor and therefore this throws a TypeError. You really want the first answer above.

Comment: This is far more elegant than the accepted answer for situations where you're trying to distinguish between arrays and objects in js.

Comment: @countfloortiles: yes and no - `someObject.constructor = Object` and the test will return true from there on.

Comment: @countfloortiles: `.constructor` can be overridden, so using it for type checking is not 100% safe.

Comment: @CoDEmanX But so can `Object.prototype.toString = function() { return '[object Object]' }`. Then `Object.prototype.toString.call( someObject ) === '[object Object]'` will return true from thereon.

Comment: I believe the `instanceof` operator is better since it will support null values and also check the full prototype hierarchy.

Comment: @AramKocharyan `([])  instanceof Object` returns true. Nowadays it can be just used `someObject?.constructor === Object`

Answer (score 3):

I think a function like this should be native, just like `Array.isArray`:

```
Object.isObject = function(obj) {
    return obj && obj.constructor === this || false;
};
```

This one doesn't make function calls nor string comparisons, and doesn't reference global objects (like `Object`), so it should be quite fast. I don't think this will used in performance intensive tasks though, but whatever.

I'm not totally convinced about the name... maybe something like `Object.isLiteral` would be better.

It can cause problem with host objects, though, but I don't have a test ready.

Comment: the `|| false` part is pretty unnecessary.

Comment: @naomik It's not if you want the function to always return a boolean. If `obj === null` it'd return `null` instead. You can always go for `return obj != null && object.constructor === this;`.

Comment: The other way is `return !!(obj && obj.constructor === this)`

Comment: or even better `return !!obj && obj.constructor === this` – also worth explicitly mentioning that you're really just doing `return !!obj && obj.constructor === Object`, in case someone wants to do this elsewhere.  I do see your speed note but either way it's veryyyy fast

Answer (score 3):

If you use `obj instanceof Object` or `typeof obj === "object"` you get false positives on things like `new Number(3)` and arrays (`[1,2,3]`).

Using `o.constructor === Object` is great, however there's a weird edge case of `Object.create(null)` – which does, in fact, give you a plain object, albeit not one created in a "normal" way.  Conceptually it gives a valid, normal, undecorated object.  We check for this case with `Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === null` which will only hold true for the above undecorated object type.

The `!!o` converts `null` or `undefined` to `false`. People were complaining about it above, and honestly `o && ...` is more succinct and unless you're serializing it doesn't matter.  Nevertheless, I included it.

```
function isObject(o) {
  return o && o.constructor === Object
}

function isObject1(o) {
  return !!o && o.constructor === Object
}

function isObject2(o) {
  // edge case where you use Object.create(null) –– which gives an object {} with no prototype
  return !!o && (Object.getPrototypeOf(o) === null || o.constructor === Object)
}
```

Comment: As somebody who has mostly used `!!` in the past, I now think `Boolean(o)` more clearly expresses the intent (same reason I don't use the unary operator to convert a string to a number, but rather `Number(str)`)

Answer (score 2):

Say you have some `testvar` and want to see if it is an object, but  not an array or null (these are both of type Object).  You can do the following

```
testVar instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(testVar) && testVar !== null
```

Comment: what about `const testVar = new Number(2)`

Comment: The new Number(2) call generates a Number object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), so it would evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, I'm seeing different values for toString() for a subclassed object depending how toString() is being called:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(aThing)
"[object Object]"

aThing.toString()
"ZmPopupMenu"
```

That results in a false positive, so I amended it to prefer the object's toString():

```
var str = someObject.toString
    ? someObject.toString()
    : Object.prototype.toString.call(someObject);
return str === '[object Object]';
```

Comment: If an objects `toString` property is overridden by a function returning a different value, `alert`, for example, will display that value. However, `Object.prototype.toString.call( anObject )` will always return the string `[object Object]` if `anObject` indeed is an object. To have `Object.prototype.toString` return something different, the `Object`’s prototype `toString` must itself be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need to check everything by yourself or write your own codes, when there are good libraries such as ***[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs)*** and ***[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org)***.

In Lodash, you can easily check it by isPlainObject function, e.g.:

```
_.isPlainObject({'a': 12});
```

Check this page: https://lodash.com/docs#isPlainObject

Comment: Just to be clear, Underscore has no such function - it does have _.isObject but that does not check for a plain object / object literal (e.g. it returns true also for an array)

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla Javascript version of [JQuery.isPlainObject](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject) function.

```
var class2type = {};
var toString = class2type.toString;
var getProto = Object.getPrototypeOf;
var hasOwn = class2type.hasOwnProperty;
var fnToString = hasOwn.toString;
var ObjectFunctionString = fnToString.call(Object);

function isPlainObject(obj) {
  var proto, Ctor;

  // Detect obvious negatives
  // Use toString instead of jQuery.type to catch host objects
  if (!obj || toString.call(obj) !== "[object Object]") {
    return false;
  }

  proto = getProto(obj);

  // Objects with no prototype (e.g., `Object.create( null )`) are plain
  if (!proto) {
    return true;
  }

  // Objects with prototype are plain iff they were constructed by a global Object function
  Ctor = hasOwn.call(proto, "constructor") && proto.constructor;
  return typeof Ctor === "function" && fnToString.call(Ctor) === ObjectFunctionString;
}
```

**Example:**

```
isPlainObject({}) // true
isPlainObject( "test" ) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const isObject = (x) => {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) == "[object Object]";
}
```

That works for me.

Comment: isObject(new Thing()) => true

Answer (score 0):

adding to user [user113716:](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/user113716) (public utility)

```
function typeOfObj(obj) {
    if(typeof obj === 'function' && String(obj).search('class') === 0) return 'class';
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).replace(/.*\w*\s(\w*).*/,'$1').toLowerCase();
}

if(typeof obj !== 'undefined' && typeOfObj(obj) == 'object') true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Obj && typeof Obj === 'object' && !Array.isArray(Obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

Bumping old thread, but it's still shows up in searches and people are even referencing it as duplicate for a new similar ones - and still the top-most answers here are **far** from being correct (sorry people, no offends).

To check if variable is an object the following should be used:

```
if (typeof variable === 'object') {
    // do something
}
```

Arrays are also objects, so this would be true for an array too.
Moreover - `null` is a valid object as well, therefore the above will return true on `null` too.
Personally, when really need to check if an expected variable is 'workable' object I'm always using this boringly repeated formula:

```
if (variable && typeof variable === `object`) {
    // do something
}
```

Last but not least :) please please please, do yourself a favor and don't use any libraries for such a simple things. Javascript is a fastly evolving language having today much much more than yesterday, so fast that most of the libraries are not even fast enough to fetch up.
Beside it, people who are working on the spec are doing a great job and mostly the native APIs are clean, correct, making perfect sense and coherent with the rest of the language.

Answer (score -1):

Little gist, not really elegant but efficient

```
function _isObj( _obj ){

   return ( typeof _obj === "object" && JSON.stringify( _obj ).indexOf( "{" ) == 0 ); 

}
```

Little example

```js
function _isObj( _obj ){

   return ( typeof _obj === "object" && JSON.stringify( _obj ).indexOf( "{" ) == 0 ); 

}

var p = document.createElement( "p" );
p.textContent = "undefined : " + _isObj( undefined );
document.body.appendChild( p );

p = document.createElement( "p" );
p.textContent = "null : " + _isObj( null );
document.body.appendChild( p );

p = document.createElement( "p" );
p.textContent = "boolean : " + _isObj( true );
document.body.appendChild( p );

p = document.createElement( "p" );
p.textContent = "function : " + _isObj( function(){} );
document.body.appendChild( p );

p = document.createElement( "p" );
p.textContent = "array : " + _isObj( [] );
document.body.appendChild( p );

p = document.createElement( "p" );
p.textContent = "string : " + _isObj( "{}" );
document.body.appendChild( p );
document.body.appendChild( p );
document.body.appendChild( p );

p = document.createElement( "p" );
p.textContent = "number : " + _isObj( 1 );
document.body.appendChild( p );
document.body.appendChild( p );

p = document.createElement( "p" );
p.textContent = "object : " + _isObj( {} );
document.body.appendChild( p );

p = document.createElement( "p" );
p.textContent = "another object : " + _isObj( p );
document.body.appendChild( p );
```

hope this help

Comment: `_isObj(new Buffer(1)) // true`

Comment: @Mirek why you test "new Buffer(1)" ,  scenario ?

Answer (score -2):

This works for me:

```
function isObject(o) {
    try {
        return ((typeof o == "object") && (o !== null) && (o.length === undefined));
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
}
```