# Next-Auth session returning undefined from getServerSideProps, NextJS 13.2.1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-auth

In the following code, `session` is undefined when logging from the client after getting passed from `getServerSideProps`.

```js
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';
import { authOptions } from './api/auth/[...nextauth]';
import StandardRecipeLogo from 'components/display/StandardRecipeLogo';
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import { Session } from 'next-auth';

const redirectUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/signin';

export default function Home({ session }: { session: Session }) {
  console.log(session);
  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="flex items-center border-b mx-10 py-4">
        <StandardRecipeLogo styles={{ div: 'flex-1' }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const session = await getServerSession(context.req, context.res, authOptions);
  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: redirectUrl,
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
  console.log('session', session);
  return {
    props: {
      session: session,
    },
  };
};
```

However, changing the `getServerSideProps` return statement to extract the `user` object works fine, and the user is logged correctly on the client. What's going on here and why does passing the full session not work? The code that works:

```js
  return {
    props: {
      user: session.user,
    },
  };
```

```js
export default function Home({ user }: any) {
  console.log(user);
  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="flex items-center border-b mx-10 py-4">
        <StandardRecipeLogo styles={{ div: 'flex-1' }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The entire session object logs perfectly fine within getServerSideprops, but disappears after getting passed to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Props that you are passing from the server should be serializable. most likely some of the properties of `session` is undefined. so object is not serializable. to test if `session`serializable use this function from [Reliable way to check if objects is serializable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579940/reliable-way-to-check-if-objects-is-serializable-in-javascript)

```
function isSerializable(obj) {
  var isNestedSerializable;
  function isPlain(val) {
    return (typeof val === 'undefined' || typeof val === 'string' || typeof val === 'boolean' || typeof val === 'number' || Array.isArray(val) || _.isPlainObject(val));
  }
  if (!isPlain(obj)) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if (!isPlain(obj[property])) {
        return false;
      }
      if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
        isNestedSerializable = isSerializable(obj[property]);
        if (!isNestedSerializable) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```