# javascript, is there an isObject function like isArray?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check that value is object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320767/check-that-value-is-object-literal)

I am working with an output that can be either null, 0, or a json object. And with that I need to come up with a means of determining if that output is indeed a real object. But I can't find anything that gives me a definitive answer as to if there is something like that in the javascript functionality or not. If there isn't is there a means otherwise that I can detect if this is an object?

Comment: Hmm looks like that answer could be up the ally of what I am looking for, seems like a work around but. If thats the best there is, ill take it :-D

Comment: Try this 
`isObject: function(arg) {
   return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg).indexOf('Object') !== -1;
  }`

Comment: Object.prototype.toString.call(variable) === '[object Object]'

Comment: Since Array's are predefined objects in JavaScript, I've used typeof and checking the constructor for an `isObject(A)` utility: `A && typeof A === 'object' && A.constructor === Object`

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator.

```
if( (typeof A === "object" || typeof A === 'function') && (A !== null) )
{
    alert("A is object");
}
```

Note that because `typeof new Number(1) === 'object'` while `typeof Number(1) === 'number';` the first syntax should be avoided.

Comment: looks like theres a potential draw back to that, as `null` could result in a false positive.

Comment: ahh, clearly Im getting tired, I didnt think of that to prevent false positive. Good call, I think im gonna give this a shot and see how it works

Comment: @chris If you use jQuery, think it did all the job for you to prevent false positive.

Comment: Try `A = []`. Arrays are objects as well :)

Comment: @dfsq, you're right. But the question was about distinguishing between null, 0, or a json object. And array `[]` is also json object :)

Comment: @bhovhannes JSON is not an object though...

Comment: @VisioN, yes, I just quoted the question. I meant it we have null values, 0 values, and some object, we can check for object (it doesn't matter if it is array or not) using code in the answer.

Comment: @bhovhannes, in that case, you could just use `if (A && typeof A == 'object')`

Comment: @Klaus, although result is the same, my version works slightly faster, since it is using strict comparison. Here is the link illustrating this: http://jsperf.com/null-0-object

Comment: It will alert *A is object* incorrectly if `A = new Number(123)` or similar (`A = new String(...)` etc.)

Comment: thanks for remark @CoDEmanX, the question was about distinguishing between null, 0, or a json object. For that case my code is sufficient. It will work also for `Number(123)` but not for `new Number(123)`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hey!, This is wrong. You could check the constructor and see if it equals to Object. If you have  let item =  { id:3, desc:"item" } 

you could check if it's exactly an Object(excluding Array, null, etc) using the 

item.constructor === Object

Comment: Also this is problematic because an array will also have typeof === 'object', so this doesn't distinguish between arrays and objects.

Comment: `function isObject(A) {  return A === null || (A && A.toString() === "[object Object]"); }`

the above is more reliable than checking `typeof A === "object" ` cause the latter will also return true if A is an array or A=new Number(8).

Comment: No, you cant, 'object' == typeof []

Answer (score 63):

use the following

It will return a true or false

```
theObject instanceof Object
```

Comment: -1 `[] instanceof object === true`

Comment: @naomik Why the downvote? The accepted answer returns true for arrays as well, and besides that's what the OP asked for. Also, this method is [faster](http://jsperf.com/is-it-an-object) than the accepted one and doesn't involve an extra check for null; making it easier to read as well. I wish I could upvote ten times.

Comment: @rvighne, I downvoted that answer too. Based on the question, it seems like the OP wants to differentiate an object from an array. You're going to get false positives using this method.

Comment: @naomik An array *is* an object. And JSON root elements can be arrays as well as objects, try `JSON.parse("[1,2,3]")`. The OP said they don't want 0 or null.

Comment: @rvighne, doing a jsPerf with different types of value being tested in sequence, it appears that typeof might be faster. http://jsperf.com/instanceof-vs-typeof-for-plain-objects

This is a perfectly valid answer, but might not be the fastest if the type of the object expected to be inconsistent.

Comment: -1 because `instanceof` fails for objects from different frames. http://perfectionkills.com/instanceof-considered-harmful-or-how-to-write-a-robust-isarray/

Comment: `function isObject(o) { return o instanceof Object && !(o instanceof Array); }`

Comment: Additionally, unlike the accepted answer, this will think Object.create(null) is not an object.

Comment: Seems like it is the most acceptable tradeoff

Comment: functions also are instances of `Object`, as well as instances of `Function`.

Answer (score 12):

In jQuery there is [`$.isPlainObject()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/) method for that:

> Description: Check to see if an object is a plain object (created
>   using "{}" or "new Object").

Comment: Great, but with a caveat: "Note: Host objects (or objects used by browser host environments to complete the execution environment of ECMAScript) have a number of inconsistencies which are difficult to robustly feature detect cross-platform. As a result of this, $.isPlainObject() may evaluate inconsistently across browsers in certain instances."

Comment: And the native version would be: `(obj instanceof Object && !(obj instanceof Array))`

Comment: Only good answer actually... @StevenVachon: fails for `obj = new Number(123)`

Comment: Object.isPlainObject() to go with Array.isArray() please!

Comment: @JoshMc These are rather new methods that modern browsers started to support recently. 3 years ago with that question most browsers didn't know anything about it, so complicated vanilla and short jQuery solutions were sort of best practice.

Comment: For those interested in implementation details of jQuery's `isPlainObject`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/d0ce00cdfa680f1f0c38460bc51ea14079ae8b07/src/core.js#L204-L223