# Destructuring Nested objects in javascript | Destructure second level parent and child Objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, nested-object

I need to destructure and get values of title, child, childTitle from this object

```
const obj1 = {
   title : 'foo',
   child : {
       title2 : 'bar'
   }
}

let {title, child} = obj1;
console.log(title)   // 'foo'
console.log(child)   // { title : 'bar' } 

// but couldn't get child object this way

let { title , child : { title2 } } = obj1;
console.log(title)   // 'foo'
console.log(child)   // undefined
console.log(title2)  // 'bar'
```

How could I get the child object?

Comment: What do you mean get?  You can't console log the object, but you can do other things with objects.  Like using typeOf: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13045455/8716187

Comment: ^^^ changing the code, yes you can ^^^

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code hmmmmmm, yes objects can be logged in console. The question is more towards getting(destructuring) the child object along with some child property.  Tq anyways

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`child: { title2 }` is just destructuring the child property. If you want to pick up the child property itself simply specify it in the statement: `let { title, child, child: { title2 } } = obj1;`

```js
const obj1 = {
  title: 'foo',
  child: {
    title2: 'bar'
  }
}

let { title, child, child: { title2 } } = obj1;

console.log(title);
console.log(child); 
console.log(title2);
```

Answer (score 4):

When doing child : `{ child : { title2 } }`, `child` is not instantiate, so you can still doing `{ child, child : { title2 } }` to get both `title2` and `child`.

As simple as :

```
const obj1 = {
  title: "foo",
  child: {
    title2: "bar"
  }
};

const { title, child, child : { title2 } } = obj1
```